# Changing color in one char on a button text

Tags: c#, colors

I have a problem with a specific problem. I have a font with symbols on letters, means that if you type "Afg" you get three symbols and the Afg letters. All is good but i want to write A in black, f in red and in black color of font, and put them as Text in the Button.Text. It would be help me a lot cos if this is not working i would be in press to make about 500 jpegs and load it in every button where i want.
More Simply i want the text on a button have Afg as A  f  g.
And Afg as a text with color red f in a button.text.

Comment: xaml or code-behind, forms or wpf?

Comment: WinForms, is just a Virtual Keyboard App but in keys on keyboad i dont want letters, i m getting symbols from a font that have music symbols. Is working as a font but all is black, cant find the way to color one char from 3 ex.

Comment: Can you not just use the paint routine? you would need to draw the label yourself, however, you can do so.

Comment: @Karajohann as said in comments under the answer of thomas, you could use richtextboxes where you can set foreground color

Comment: @Karajohann I need a condition to give you an example AFG isn't enough.. do you want all `f` red? or every 2nd character or what?

Comment: only f red, the ather 2 black. Its radomly. Maybe the other button i ll need the first letter be red, next button ll have 2 letters etc is not the same the number of letters or the position of red char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native control in windows forms for example that allows that. 
You can write your own control to allow multiple colors in Button text.

Also, you can place the RichTextBox in front of the button and set the color accordingly:

```
    RichTextBox RichTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
    RichTextBox1.Location = Button1.Location;
    RichTextBox1.Text = "abc";
    RichTextBox1.Select(0, 1);
    RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    RichTextBox1.Select(1, 2);
    RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
    RichTextBox1.Select(2, 3);
    RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    RichTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    RichTextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    RichTextBox1.BackColor = underlying form BackColor
```

Comment: You could use several [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) e.g. `richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 1;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;`

Comment: You mean if i have a string "qwe" i will RichTextBox with richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black for q, RichTextBox with richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red for w and RichTextBox with richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black for e? Ok but could you give me the way to combine them and pass the "qwe" to Button.Text with this colors?

Comment: @Tomáš Kratochvíla Working perfect Just i fix. RichTextBox1.Text = "abc"; must ne declare before coloring sections